# Parenthesis in Eclipse Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Hi.

As you know, if there is already a Run configuration for a given

class with main type, Eclipse gives parenthesis and number at the

tail of the class name as in the attached image.

But even when there is no preexisting class with conflicting name,

why do I see it with paranthesized number at the end of (main type)

program name, like program(1), program(2)?

Do you have any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Launch Configurations window, there's a filter button in the toolbar (the "triple arrows" icon at the top of your screen shot). Clicking that drop-down allows to filter out (or not) various types of launches, including those that belong to closed or missing projects. If you un-check all of the filters you should be able to see the conflicting launch that's causing the name conflict.

Comment: You are the greatest!

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it so credit is given.

Comment: Oh, I thought just pressing "UP" button next to your solution text means accepting it. Let me find a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell me how to accept an answer as a solution so that you can get score?

Comment: I have never realized that there exists "check" symbol beside an answer. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this before in Eclipse where I had a project with a runnable class (lets say the class was called MainRun) and then I close or delete the project from the Eclipse workspace. The MainRun run configuration disappears from the "Run Configurations" list. But if you later create a new project with a class called MainRun that you want to run, it somehow remembers that you used to have a configuration called MainRun, even though it is no longer in the list, and so your new one has to be MainRun (1). Could this be what is happening to you?

Comment: It seems so. I checked the .metadata and .settings, but there was nothing that saves preference for a given main type class.

Comment: Yeah same, when I had this issue I checked loads of the random .* files, but couldn't figure out where it was being saved. I never really dug deeper as it didn't bother me that much TBH